# Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MSGesture' in trying to create application with BabyloneJS

Tags: typescript, npm, tsc, babylonjs

Trying to follow instructions at: https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js. In npm, when I compile a single-line "main.ts" program containing  `import * as BABYLON from 'babylonjs';` with tsc, I get these errors:

```
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(24692,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MouseWheelEvent'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(24706,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MouseWheelEvent'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(24732,57): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MouseWheelEvent'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(24749,57): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MouseWheelEvent'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(32168,81): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvas'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(40274,162): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvas'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(40704,54): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvas'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(40706,62): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(40772,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvas'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(41765,54): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvas'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(41767,62): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(105418,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MouseWheelEvent'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(105432,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MouseWheelEvent'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(105458,57): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MouseWheelEvent'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(105475,57): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MouseWheelEvent'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(112575,81): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvas'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(120467,162): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvas'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(120866,54): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvas'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(120868,62): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(120934,67): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvas'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(121922,54): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvas'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(121924,62): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(158921,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MSGesture'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(158963,78): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NavigatorUserMediaSuccessCallback'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(158963,128): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NavigatorUserMediaErrorCallback'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(158964,75): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NavigatorUserMediaSuccessCallback'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(158964,125): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NavigatorUserMediaErrorCallback'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(158965,74): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NavigatorUserMediaSuccessCallback'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(158965,124): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'NavigatorUserMediaErrorCallback'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(159157,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WebGLObject'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(159165,32): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WebGLObject'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(159173,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WebGLObject'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(159181,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WebGLObject'.
    ../../../../../../node_modules/babylonjs/babylon.module.d.ts(159189,42): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WebGLObject'.
```

The tsconfig.json is:

```
{
   "files": ["main.ts"],
   "compilerOptions": {
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "declaration": true,
      "types": ["babylonjs"],
      "target": "es2015"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use the older version of Typescript supported by Babylonjs:
`npm install -g typescript@4.0.2`.